# .NET Setup Project Launch Conditions Custom Message Boxes

Tags: c#, .net, windows-installer

I would like to know, whether there is a way to customize the messageboxes that are displayed in case a "Launch Condition" is evaluated to false?
I am using a "MSI Setup Project".
To subscribe this with an example:

If I require .NET 4 to be installed on the target-machine and it is not installed, there will be a message box, telling the user that he needs to install .NET 4 in order to install my program.
Can I tell .NET how the message box should look like? (Including pictures, etc. ...)

Comment: If upgrading to VS2012 is likely, **do not use .vdproj**. It no longer exists. Consider learning WiX instead.

Comment: In addition to wix, there's also http://sharpsetup.eu